# Grouping CSV lines into one

Tags: c#, linq, csv

I have a CSV file that has rows, where data for some columns only appear in one of those rows, with other columns repeating their value:

```
Heading1, Heading2, Heading3, Heading4
1       , 2       ,         , 4
1       ,         , 3       , 4
```

How can I end up with:

```
Heading1, Heading2, Heading3, Heading4
1       , 2       , 3       , 4
```

I want to group on Heading1 and Heading4 as they are unique to the repeated rows and get the first non-blank value for all other rows, ending up with a single `string[]`.

I've got as far as grouping on `new { Header1, Header4 }` to get a group of rows, but I'm having a hard time turning that into something where I can select the first non null value for each column, then turning it back into a single row (`string[]`).

Ideally I'd like a function that works with any number of columns as in the actual file there are a large number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Make an array of length 4 with values initialized to some to empty strings (or zeros as appropriate).
- For each non-header row, loop over the fields, storing the value in the corresponding array position whenever the field value is not blank.
- Write-out the values in the array to the new CSV file.

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense - I think I was stuck in the LINQ frame of mind. That said, a function that reads in CSV lines and produces CSV lines (internally using the method you describe, together with `yield`) might be useful.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett sounds like you're on the right track at this point.  Good luck with your project :-)

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with LINQ using Aggregate.  Create a function to compare the *running totals* with the current row, setting the *total* for the column to the current value for the column if the total is not empty and the current value is not empty.

```
[TestMethod]
public void MergeArrays() {

    string[] Input = new[] { 
        "H1, H2, H3, H4",
        "1,2,,4",
        "1,,3,4"
    };


    var header = Input.ElementAt(0) ;
    var aggregation = string.Join(",", Input.Skip(1).Select(ln => ln.Split(',')).Aggregate(new[] { "", "", "", "" }, Agg));

    var result = new string[] { header, aggregation };


    Assert.AreEqual("H1, H2, H3, H4", header);
    Assert.AreEqual("1,2,3,4", aggregation);


}


private static string[] Agg(string[] aggregation, string[] input) {

    for (var idx = 0; idx < aggregation.GetLength(0); idx++) {
        if (aggregation[idx] == string.Empty &&input[idx] !=  string.Empty){
            aggregation[idx] = input[idx];
        }
    }

    return aggregation;

}
```

hth, 
Alan.